# CloudKit CKError "Invalid Arguments" with "Bad sync continuation data"

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm working on Xcode 8.3 with iOS 10 and I followed Apple's [Cloud Kit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH12-SW1) document for maintaining a local cache of cloud data, and my device was able to receive push notification when the data in a private database zone was changed, but when trying to fetch the zone changes I always get the following errors:

```
2017-06-17 11:58:11.376807-0400 MyApp[10694:5029263] received remote notification
2017-06-17 11:58:11.897402-0400 MyApp[10694:5031532] fetch database change completed
2017-06-17 11:58:11.897606-0400 MyApp[10694:5031532] zone deletions
2017-06-17 11:58:12.320908-0400 MyApp[10694:5031561] record zone fetch completed
Error fetching zone changes for private database: <CKError 0x170256620: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server message = "Bad sync continuation data"; uuid = xxxxxxxx-EFD7-459D-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx; container ID = "iCloud.com.mycompany.MyApp">
2017-06-17 11:58:12.332247-0400 MyApp[10694:5031561] fetch record zone changes completed
Error fetching zone changes for private database: <CKError 0x174640150: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Couldn't fetch some items when fetching changes"; uuid = xxxxxxxx-EFD7-459D-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx; container ID = "iCloud.com.mycompany.MyApp"; partial errors: {
PrivateZone:__defaultOwner__ = <CKError 0x170254670: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server message = "Bad sync continuation data">
}>
```

The "Bad sync continuation data" is quite confusing as I cannot find an explanation of this error in Apple's document or find any reference in google search. Does anyone encounter this before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After pondering more about the meaning of "continuation" in this context, and digging deeper into the Apple example, I realized the problem was that I just kept one variable for server change tokens returned at different fetch change stages, as represented by the `fetchDatabaseChanges` and `fetchZoneChanges` methods. After adding variables to track the database change tokens and zone change tokens (each zone has its own), the "Bad sync continuation data" error disappeared and I can see changed records returned from server.

Comment: I had the same issue. Do I understand you correctly that every database (private, shared, public) has its own change token and every zone (default, ...)? When I adapted these changes in the example code from Apple the above errors disappear, however the cloud deamon crashes and I get these kind of error messages: `[LogFacilityCK] Got a connection error for operation B6D7CD06813D5F2E: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.cloudd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.cloudd}` Maybe you could share your adapted example code?

Comment: Hi, @Daniel, yes that's what I understand from this exercise, that each database and zone has their own change tokens. I don't see these LogFacilityCK errors if I only fetchDatabaseChanges/fetchZoneChanges after receiving remote notifications generated by server side changes, but I played around and I do see these errors if I proactively fetch changes before receiving any notifications, say if I want to fetch changes at the start of the app. Is this what is going on in your code too? If it is, I guess maybe fetching changes without any new changes on server may cause some cloudKit side error.

Comment: To confirm this error is caused by fetching without any changes on server side, I tried putting my app into background, then make some changes on the server side, then wake the app up which would trigger a fetchChanges call. In this case the app successfully fetched the changes without any error. Going through this exercise again without making any server side change does cause the 4097 error again.

Comment: Interesting. I don't receive notifications yet somehow. Not sure why. (My app runs in macOS) I get these errors because of this line at startup: `createZoneGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) {
            if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "CreatedCustomZone") {
                self.fetchChanges(in: .private) {}
                self.fetchChanges(in: .shared) {}
            }
        }` Even if the app is not running at all, I make changes to some records on the dashboard and then start it, it causes the 4097 errors.

Comment: Okay, one thing I was doing wrong was that I saved a record into the default zone, but fetching changes from the default zone is not supported. Now I also receive the change notifications. But still 4097 errors. I can't imagine  that fetching changes without any new changes on server causes the errors, even though it looks like that.

Comment: Right, default zone doesn't support pushing/fetching. I would imagine the right way to implement this in CloudKit is just return nothing or some message indicating no changes instead of returning 4097, but unfortunately it looks like that's the behavior right now.

Comment: I managed to get rid of all errors. Don't ask me how exactly. First of all I removed everything that has to do with the shared DB, because I don't need it at the moment. It also helped to do a fresh install of my app by removing all cached data. The cloud deamon also crashed if I tried to create a zone that has already been created, so be careful there.

Comment: @Daniel so you don't see the errors even if you try to fetch changes when there's no change on server? I'm not using Shared DB either and I do check a saved parameter indicating if I have created the zone already.

Comment: That's correct. No errors with fetching changes (with a change token) - I've uploaded my basic CloudKitController here: https://gist.github.com/Iomegan/c633251dc5ac18a983a4a4a48acd599b  Maybe there's something you do differently...

Comment: Yeah, so just to be clear, you need to save a ChangeToken for the database, and 1 for each zone in that database.  In my case, I set up one zone in my shared database, and so in the Apple example I saved the database change token in fetchDatabaseChanges, and a Zone Token in fetchZoneChanges, under different names, and then everything started working wonderfully.

Comment: Thank you, I know i'm a bit late to the party but this helped me solve an issue that I have been having for a week.